# How to get rid of all special characters using vba

Tags: regex, vba

My data contains `#, / , '` etc. How can I get rid of all those things and substitute them with `""` . I want to apply this to `Sheet1` all cells ?

Comment: A find regex might be `[#/']+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub RemoveSpecChars()
    Dim Token As Variant
    For Each Token In Array("-", "\", "#")  'etc.
        Sheet1.UsedRange.Replace Token, ""
    Next Token
End Sub
```

Comment: If performance is a concern you can turn screen updating off at the beginning of the sub (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`) and turn it back on before the end of the sub (`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`).

Comment: Usually something like this takes a very large amount of time since it starts at the beginning on each token, not to mention possible memory reallocation, and it only handles single character replacement at a time.

Comment: Obviously it depends on the size of the UsedRange and the number of tokens.  I tested it on a moderately sized sheet where UsedRange.Count = 135702.  It ran in about 2 seconds.  When performance started to fall off, it would likely fall off dramatically.

Comment: After rereading, I realize my comment about ScreenUpdating may have been misleading.  Turning off ScreenUpdating will not fundamentally improve the performance of this approach.  As you point out, it will certainly bog down with a large dataset.  That said, it is a simple, easy-to-understand approach and will be more than sufficient in many circumstances.

Comment: In my experience (I do a lot of translations of text in c++), its always a red flag when replacing multiple different characters itteratively, as opposed to once. Usually by more than a few magnitude in speed.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, though, what you are suggesting as an alternative is not a viable option in Excel.  Regex replace is possible, but not for an entire range.  So the choices boil down to: 1) use the Range Replace method a handful of times (once per token) or 2) use the VBScript RegEx Replace method to replace multiple tokens at a time, but on a per-cell basis; resulting in (potentially) thousands of iterations.  I understand your point in general, but given the Excel environment, I believe this is a reasonable approach.